# Changing color of text for specific amount of time in C# and Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I'm currently working on a game in Unity and I have a small problem. I'm trying to create an  effect where the color of the ingame score counter temporarily changes color when the score counter gets incremented and then switches back to it's original color. However when I attempt to do this my game keeps on crashing. I'm using a while loop in order to preform this task but as soon as I try to trigger this event in game my game aswell as Unity crash. Does anyone know why this happens and maybe have a solution in order to solve this?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

    public class StarCollision : MonoBehaviour
    {


        private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
        {

            if (other.gameObject.tag == "White Ball" )
            { 
            gameObject.SetActive(false);
             ScoreScript.scoreValue += 1;

                 while (Time.deltaTime < 0.2f)
                 {
                     ScoreScript.score.color = Color.yellow;
                 } 

             ScoreScript.score.color = Color.white;


            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Also, use `other.gameObject.CompareTag("White Ball")` instead of `other.gameObject.tag == "White Ball"`

Comment: Also, don't prefer to use tags, its very bad refactorable

Comment: Do you get an error message or stack trace when it crashes? If so, can you add it to the question please.

Comment: @KieranDevlin it freezes actually due to the `while loop` ... there will be no Exception

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Coroutines and its WaitForSeconds method

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class StarCollision : MonoBehaviour
{
    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("White Ball"))
        { 
            ScoreScript.scoreValue += 1;
            StartCoroutine(ChangeColor());
        }
    }

    private IEnumerator ChangeColor ()
    {
         ScoreScript.score.color = Color.yellow;
         yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.2f);
         ScoreScript.score.color = Color.white;
         gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: cept now you arent using other so didnt need to pass it :P

Comment: @Maurice Bekambo You are welcome, mark it like an answer than)

Answer (score 3):

Your `while` loop is blocking the Main/UI thread => it is executed and the next frame only rendered after it finished!

Additionally [`Time.deltaTime`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-deltaTime.html) is the time passed since the last frame was rendered ... so it might **never** reach `0.2` since assuming you run at `60 fps` it's value will be about `0.017` => Unity freezes!

You should use a [Coroutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html) instead:

```
public class StarCollision : MonoBehaviour
{
    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.tag == "White Ball" )
        { 
            ScoreScript.scoreValue += 1;

            // start the routine
            StartCoroutine(ChangeColor());

            gameObject.SetActive(false);
        }
    }

    private IEnumerator ChangeColor()
    {
        ScoreScript.score.color = Color.yellow;

        // yield says: return to main thread, renderer the frame
        // and continue from here in the next frame
        // WaitForseconds .. does exactly this
        yield return new WaitForseconds(0.2f);

        ScoreScript.score.color = Color.white;
    }
}
```

---

I would leave your `gameObject.SetActive(false);` before the Coroutine finished but **after** it started since you want it immediately and

> Note: [Coroutines](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html) are not stopped when a `MonoBehaviour` is disabled, but only when it is definitely destroyed. You can stop a Coroutine using `MonoBehaviour.StopCoroutine` and `MonoBehaviour.StopAllCoroutines`. Coroutines are also stopped when the `MonoBehaviour` is destroyed.

Comment: Tho `gameObject.SetActive(false);` will stop the script immediately

Comment: `Tho gameObject.SetActive(false); will stop the script immediately` @caxapexac no that is not true: [Coroutines](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html) -> `Note: Coroutines are not stopped when a MonoBehaviour is disabled, but only when it is definitely destroyed. You can stop a Coroutine using MonoBehaviour.StopCoroutine and MonoBehaviour.StopAllCoroutines. Coroutines are also stopped when the MonoBehaviour is destroyed.`

Comment: But you deactivate GameObject not in coroutine

Comment: yes but I don't destroy it so the routine will continue

Comment: oh thanks now I also made a mistake .. you were semi-correct: You have to start the coroutine before disabling the object but than it continues ;)

Comment: That was what I mean)

Answer (score -1):

You have to use a `Coroutine`for that. Check out https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html

Basically you just yield one frame at each iteration of the loop, for the amount of time you want, or you yield for a specific amount of time.

Hope it helped

Comment: Not true, you can wait for seconds, which is a float.

Comment: Both works, why do you downvote ? Both can be used and serves different purposes

Comment: because its not a complete answer - you didnt demonstrate how to do anything other than post an external link

Comment: It's more a comment than the answer